# Always on availability failover for SharePoint farm is failing to connect in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2013, sql-server-2014, high-availability, failovercluster

We have SharePoint farm in front end 2013.
We are using sql server 2014 enterprise edition .

Initially, SharePoint farm is connected to Server A.
But we wanted to configure Always On availability for this.
We configured it from Sql end.**Server B is the secondary replica**.

And we have configured the listener also.
After configuring the listener we have given the listener name and IP to SharePoint team.
They have changed alias name to Listner name in client connection side.
After that we have done possible scenarios to test the failover.

But, the failover scenarios got failed.
We have observed one common issue in all the scenarios.
After failing over to Server B, SharePoint is not redirecting to Server B, it is still trying to connect to Server A only.
When we down the Server A, SharePoint also is going down.

When we failed over to Server B ( primary )and Server A is available and acts as readable secondary.
At this point of time SharePoint website is in readable state.

Here, the observation is that SharePoint farm is only depending on Server A state.

We have requested the SharePoint team to forget about always on and listener and try to connect to Server B directly.
They have changed some settings in cliconfg.exe .

**After that, the SharePoint is again trying to access the Server A only.

What could be the reason for this?**

**Is there any other team to be involved in this to resolve this issue , apart from SQL and SharePoint.**

Quorum is configured as Witness File Share.
we only have 2 replicas, 
When server A is down , the quorum is configured between File share and Server B .
However, The Cluster is working fine, when we check the failover cluster manager immediately after Server A went down.

FS witness is not placed on either on  Server A side or server B side. It is placed on Another Server.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is what you are looking for is read only routing feature.

You have problem to route your traffic to readable secondary after failover. 
Your sharepoint always talk to AG Listener only. AG Listener will tell you who is the primary, and primary returns client(sharepoint) the secondary url to establish connection.

A lot of people doesn't understand that read only routing list is replica property. Each node has its own read only routing list. If you have issue after failover but no problem before that. I will suggest you check both Nodes read only routing list configuration. make sure  Server B ( primary ) has a list to tell client, you should go to server A. Use following query to check your configuration.

```
SELECT ar.replica_server_name "When This Server is Primary", 
    rl.routing_priority, 
    ar2.replica_server_name "Route to this Server", 
    ar.primary_role_allow_connections,
    ar.secondary_role_allow_connections_desc,   ar2.read_only_routing_url 
FROM sys.availability_read_only_routing_lists rl
  inner join sys.availability_replicas ar 
    on rl.replica_id = ar.replica_id
  inner join sys.availability_replicas ar2
    on rl.read_only_replica_id = ar2.replica_id
ORDER BY ar.replica_server_name, rl.routing_priority
```